# Algorithm to determine dimensions of matrix given a string rep

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Given a string that describes a hyper-matrix such as

```
"[[[1,2],[4,5],[6,7]]"  which is a 3,2 matrix
```

or

```
 "[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]"    which is a 2,3 matrix
```

or

```
 "[ [[1,2],[3,4],[4,6]], [[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]] ]" which is a 2,3,2 matrix
```

etc

is there a nice way to find the dimensions of the matrix? eg I'm after an algorithm that would report 2,3,2 for the third matrix. I can guarantee that each dimension has non-varying elements, ie there are no missing numbers. One can assume that the string can be tokenized into integers, commas, and left and right square brackets. I'm more interested in what approach one might use, I assume it is likely to be recursive. I toyed with the idea of building a tree but I'm not sure that helps in the end. Obviously, I can do this with python very easily using numpy and looking at shape, but I'm after suggestions for possible algorithms.

Comment: (1) Iterate through the string and maintain a variable called `depth`, initialised to 0, incremented by 1 at every '[' and decremented by 1 at every ']'. (2) While iterating through the string, count the number of commas at every depth. Keep a list of counters so that you have one counter per depth. Stop counting the commas at a given depth whenever variable `depth` becomes smaller than that depth again for the first time.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast answers, I'll study them first.

Comment: checking if a string of brackets is correctly balanced is a standard problem; see [Wikipedia: Dyck language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language). It's very useful to know how to parse a string with brackets, either using recursion or iteration. You'll need it not only to determine the dimensions of a matrix, but also to parse an arithmetic expression such as 3*(4-(5+6))

Comment: I can parse the expressions but I had a mental block for generating the dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Iterate through the string and maintain a variable called depth, initialised to 0, incremented by 1 at every '[' and decremented by 1 at every ']'.
- While iterating through the string, count the number of commas at every depth. Keep a list or dict of counters so that you have one counter per depth.
- Stop counting the commas at a given depth whenever variable depth becomes smaller than that depth again for the first time.

```py
def get_dims(mat):
  depth = 0
  capped_depth = len(mat)
  dims = {}
  for c in mat:
    if c == '[':
      depth += 1
    elif c == ']':
      if depth <= capped_depth:
        dims[depth] = dims.get(depth, 0) + 1
      depth -= 1
      capped_depth = min(depth, capped_depth)
    elif c == ',' and depth <= capped_depth:
      dims[depth] = dims.get(depth, 0) + 1
  return [v for k,v in sorted(dims.items())]

get_dims("[ [[1,2],[3,4],[4,6]], [[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]] ]")
# [2, 3, 2]

get_dims("[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]")
# [2, 3]

get_dims("[[1,2],[4,5],[6,7]]")
# [3, 2]

get_dims('[[[]]]')
# [1, 1, 1]

get_dims('[[[,]]]')
# [1, 1, 2]
```

Note that this code assumes that the string depicts a well-formed matrix. But you can easily modify the code to verify that the string is well-formed.

- The brackets are correctly nested if and only if `depth` is always positive during the for-loop, and becomes exactly 0 after the for-loop.
- The code that I wrote uses the length of the first list at every depth to compute the corresponding dimension. The matrix will be well-formed if all the lists at every given depth have the same length.

Comment: I wish I could mark both as right.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C version:

```
void printMatrixDimensions(const char *inString) {
    int depth = 0;
    int dimensions = 0;
    int *counts = NULL;
    for (const char *inString_ptr = inString; inString_ptr[0] != '\0'; inString_ptr++) {
        char c = inString_ptr[0];
        char upOrDown = 0;
        
        if (c==' ' || c=='\t' || c=='\r' || c=='\n') continue; // skip whitespace
        if (c == '[') { upOrDown = 1; } // determine if we're going down in depth
        else if (c == ']') { upOrDown = -1; } // or coming up
        depth += upOrDown;
        
        if (upOrDown == 1) { // if we're going deeper,
            if (depth > dimensions) { // expand our depths stack if needed
                dimensions = depth;
                counts = realloc(counts, sizeof(int) * dimensions);
            }
            counts[depth - 1] = 0; // initialize the new depth with a count of 0
        }
        
        if (!(c=='[' || c==']')) { // if a character other than []
            if (c==',') { // if a comma, then we have at least 2 members
                if (counts[depth - 1] == 0) counts[depth - 1] = 2;
                else counts[depth - 1] += 1;
            } else { // if a non-comma char is there, that counts for a member
                if (counts[depth - 1] == 0) counts[depth - 1] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    
    printf("Matrix dimensions:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++) {
        printf("%i ", counts[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    
    if (counts != NULL) free(counts);

}
```

Comment: I've been running the C code and was wondering if the depth should be incremented every iteration of the for loop. For example [1,2], yields 0 1 2 1 while [[1,2],[3,4]] yields 0 0 2 0 1 2 1. I'm going to check the code to see what is happening. [UPDATE] My error, I was initializing upOrDown incorrectly.  Works fine.